# Project specific access level to the users of a site in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau. Can we give project specific access to the users of a site over the Tableau server offcoarse the user will not be the site admin.

I mean user of a one site has a access to view the contents of one project but not the other project with in that site.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau's online help has extensive permissioning guidelines, examples, and best practices.

[Here is a document](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/projects.htm) regarding project level permissions. Essentially, users can be assigned permissions to particular projects and denied access to others. In addition, project owners and project leaders are roles which can be defined to delegate additional responsibilities to users.

Comment: Any luck here? If you were able to find an answer on your own please post it and give the green check mark.